# Is there a method of flipping the bits in a subnet mask to get the wildcard mask using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to make my own custom network calculator using PowerShell and ran into a snag with the wildcard mask. I've gotten stuck trying to get the wildcard mask using the subnet mask. For example, I'm currently testing using a /24 mask - 255.255.255.0 and I've converted it to it's binary value - 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000. The value I get back from performing the -bnot I would expect to be 00000000.00000000.00000000.11111111 but instead I'm getting -256.-256.-256.-1. I have tried to go bit by bit on the mask without '.' and instead I wind up with -2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1.

The following is the code I have used in order to mess with the layout of the subnet mask binary in order to work with it and the loop I was attempting to use to perform the bitwise NOT operation:

```
<pre>
$subbinarray = $subbin.ToCharArray() # Places 1 bit per row
$broadbin = ''
for ($x = 0; $x -lt 32; $x++) { # Loops through the subbinarray and performs -bnot function on each row
    $bit = -bnot [Convert]::ToUInt32($subbinarray[$x],2)
    $broadbin += $bit
}
</pre>
```

Comment: `-bnot` is returning signed values. So the last `1` bit of any value is considered negative as you may already know. I've done stupid looking stuff to get the right result --> `[Convert]::ToByte(([System.Convert]::ToString((-bnot 0),2) -replace '.*(?=.{8}$)'),2)`

Comment: So that looks like it gives me the right value but how would I use that in my loop? Would it be something like: [Convert]::ToByte(([Convert]::ToString((-bnot $x),2) -replace '.*(?=.{8}$)'),2)

Comment: `'11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000'.Replace("1", "x").Replace("0", "1").Replace("x", "0")` --> `00000000.00000000.00000000.11111111`

Comment: Using a similar principal as Theo --> `[regex]::Replace($subbin,'.',{param($m) [byte]![int]$m.Value})`

Comment: Awesome that did it thank you @Theo! Now how do I mark as solved?

Comment: @MichaelLindsay I've posted it as answer now, so you can mark as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt there are more elegant ways to do this, but you can flip the binary values like this:

```
 '11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000'.Replace("1", "x").Replace("0", "1").Replace("x", "0")
```

Result:

```
00000000.00000000.00000000.11111111
```

---

Another way of doing this:

```
$ip = '255.255.255.0'
$mask = ($ip -split '\.' | ForEach-Object {255 - [byte]$_} ) -join '.'
```

---

Yet another way is to convert the IP4 address string into its **unsigned** decimal value, use `-bnot` on that value and convert back to ip address.

```
$ip = '255.255.255.0'

# convert to UInt32
# This is now obsolete:  $ipValue = [uint32] ([System.Net.IPAddress]$ip).Address
# so we do it like this:
$a = [uint32[]]$ip.split('.')
$ipValue = [uint32]($a[3] -shl 24) + ($a[2] -shl 16) + ($a[1] -shl 8) + $a[0]

# use -bnot and convert back to IP address string:
$mask = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes(-bnot $ipValue) -join '.'
# or use: $mask = [string]([System.Net.IPAddress](-bnot $ipValue)).IPAddressToString

$mask
```

Result:

> ```
> $ip   --> '255.255.255.0'  --> 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
> $mask --> '0.0.0.255'      --> 00000000.00000000.00000000.11111111
> ```